# ruby on rails define translations for labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

how can I define translations for the form lables ..

code looks like this

```
<label><%= f.label :locked %></label>
```

how do I add this in locales correctly?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label

Comment: `<%= f.label :locked %>` on its own will give you `<label for="object_locked">Locked</label>`. You don't need the extra `<label>` tag around it.

Comment: yeah but how can I set a translateion for :locked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translations are set for a model object which is represented by `f` variable in the form. For example, if the form holds data of User model instance, then you shoud set translations like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        locked: Your Translation
```

You can find out which object is represented by `f` this way:

```
 <%= f.object %>
```